# Can't connect to SQL Server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I use XAMPP. I need to establish connection from PHP code to my MS SQL Server. Therefore, I installed the `sqlsrv` driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). According to  `phpinfo()` it's being loaded properly:
[image]

I get this error message:

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP  => -49 [code] => -49  => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for
>   x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for
>   x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 )  => Array (
>   [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002  => 0 [code] => 0  =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )

The links point to x86 client, but I can only install 64-bit version, which I did so from

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Still I get the same error.

Specs:

> OS: Windows Server 2012 64-bit
>
> PHP: 5.6.19

Code is simple as that:

```
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Now what? Shall I register that installed SQL Native Client in any of the `PHP/Apache` conf files?

Comment: What version of `sqlsrv` drivers?

Comment: @ImClarky The one compatible with PHP 5.6 -> `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`

Comment: It appears that the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack does not come with ODBC Driver 11 - which is what it is saying is missing in your connection error. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: @ImClarky It seems you're right. Copy this comment to an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://blog.dbi-services.com/sql-server-2012-feature-pack/), Microsoft's SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack does not contain ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server; which is required for `sqlsrv` extensions 3.1 and above.

- [ODBC Driver 11 Download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

check which version of php you use by using phpinfo() then download the extensions related to your version of php. Then also go to your php.ini file and add those file like so

```
extension=<extension>.dll
```

Then one vital step I was always missing and was stressing me is that you need to download the driver found on the link below... Or else your php script wont connect to your SQL Server .... Download and install this on the machine which actually has SQL Server installed... If it is a remote server this has to be installed on a remotre server... If it is on your local machine this has to be installed on your local machine...

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

[Can't connect to SQL Server from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031782/cant-connect-to-sql-server-from-php?rq=1)

Then you should be good to go...